# Javascript in Distribution.xml

Tags: javascript, macos, package, packagemaker

I'm curious where can I find a list of objects along with their methods which I can use in javascript functions for Distribution.xml part of mac os package. For example, I've studied iTunes Distribution.xml and found `system.files.plistAtPath("...")` and other system calls. I'd like to know what else can I do.

Comment: Hi, perhaps do you know if there's anyway to work with the distribution.xml javascript engine from outside the xml file (just to check your code more easily - without the need to install the package). thanks !

Comment: @Zohar81, more than 3 years I didn't touch this `distribution.xml ` stuff so I don't remember anything, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find some information in apple documentation: [Installer JavaScript Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/InstallerJavaScriptRef/). But looks like it somewhat outdated